# Windows Server 2012 RRAS/NAT with PPPoE Modem

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rras, modem, pppoe

I'm trying to connect to a BT Openreach VDSL Modem with Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials, I have RRAS with NAT set up.

My server looks like this;

- NIC 1 - Into a TP-Link Switch to connect a myriad of devices (computers, access points, etc..)
- NIC 2 - Direct connection with the Modem

In the Routing and Remote Access management console, I click "New demand-dial interface" - go through the wizard selecting PPPoE, entering the username of "bthomehub@btbroadband.com" (seems it has to be generic) with no password, then I specify the static route for it which I take from the NIC 2 (169.254.192.28) and Enter that as the Destination and Network Mask with No Gateway.

I right click on the new PPPoE interface created, click "Connect" and wait - after about 40 seconds it will error with; "The connection was closed by the remote computer" - however, if I do all this through the Network and Sharing Center" and clicking on "Setup a new connection or network" it'll work fine and create a miniport WAN (which RRAS) can't see.

Any ideas on why this would be happening and just why the Network and Sharing Center is able to connect but not a RRAS connection?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You may find this useful (although the proposed workaround is a PITA): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b8711a42-99e5-4cff-ac4d-a1d31899a325/windows-server-2012-r2-pppoe-broke-in-rras?forum=winserverPN

I suggest you open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: How come you need to use RRAS to connect to the ISP? What's wrong with just using a PPPoE adapter via Network and Sharing Center and then using that interface within RRAS to configure things as you need to? I haven't tried this myself so it's a genuine question - I'm sure you have a reason - I just can't think what it would be.